# get diagnostic data from ECU use python-uds

Tags: python, vector, can-bus, uds

I am trying to get diagnostic data from ECU.
I've tried an example but nothing works out, it always throws some exceptions.
I am using VN5620 as a CAN Interface.
I tried using the raw send command example code

```
import uds
from uds import Uds
PCM = Uds(transportProtocol="CAN", interface="vector", reqId=0x1C440019, resId=0x1C460019, appName="pythonUds", channel=1)
a = PCM.send([0x22, 0x02, 0x00])


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\companion_chip_automation\Tests\UdsOnCanTest\python_uds.py", line 4, in <module>
    PCM = Uds(transportProtocol="CAN", interface="vector", reqId=0x1C440019, resId=0x1C460019, appName="pythonUds", channel=1)
  File "C:\workspace\venv_3.8\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\Uds\Uds.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.tp = tpFactory(self.__transportProtocol, configPath=configPath, **kwargs)
  File "C:\workspace\venv_3.8\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\TransportProtocols\TpFactory.py", line 37, in __call__
    return CanTp(configPath=configPath, **kwargs)
  File "C:\workspace\venv_3.8\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\TransportProtocols\Can\CanTp.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.__connection = canConnectionFactory(self.callback_onReceive,
  File "C:\workspace\venv_3.8\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\TransportProtocols\Can\CanConnectionFactory.py", line 17, in __call__
    CanConnectionFactory.checkKwargs(**kwargs)
  File "C:\workspace\venv_3.8\lib\site-packages\uds\uds_communications\TransportProtocols\Can\CanConnectionFactory.py", line 91, in checkKwargs
    CanConnectionFactory.config['vector']['channel'] = kwargs['channel']
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\configparser.py", line 1258, in __setitem__
    self._parser._validate_value_types(option=key, value=value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\configparser.py", line 1185, in _validate_value_types
    raise TypeError("option values must be strings")
TypeError: option values must be strings
```

Could you help me to get the first response and solve this issue?

Thanks

[image: My Vector HW config:]

[image: pythonUds]

[image: CANoe (connection with CANoe works)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, actual error feels like its a bug in the python-uds. What you are passing to the Uds gets stored in ConfigParser and that's where the exception is thrown from.

Second, the error says "option values must be strings" and few rows above gives a hint that the issue is with  kwargs['channel']. You are passing `channel=1`. So, given this; maybe passing `channel="1"` would fix the issue?

Comment: I wanted to thank you very much for taking the time to help me and pointing me in the right direction. it's helpful, but now I have this error:
~can.interfaces.vector.exceptions.VectorInitializationError: xlGetApplConfig failed (Vector HW Config: Channel '1' of application 'pythonUds' is not assigned to any interface) [Error Code 255]
VectorBus was not properly shut down
~

Comment: Yeah, i was sort of expecting that .. That's why i pointed out that the issue feels like its a *bug*  in python-uds..

Comment: so what to do now?
(I have attached pictures in the body of the question)

Comment: Would you prefer I create a new question for this?

Comment: Its a **bug** in the python-uds -- it is trying to store `int` into a config file **but** stuff in configparser is always stored as `str`. Asking a question will not help. Your options are either  1) fixing the issue yourself  2) change libraries 3) contract someone to fix that issue for you 4) file a issue to python-uds and hope someone fixes that.

Comment: I understand, I would like to know where this information came from?
Anyway, thank you very much

Comment: Information came from my own findings; I cloned the repository, referred the stacktrace back to the code in repository and made small piece of code that used same approach as existing code and it threw exact same  Exception. Then i read the documetation of ConfigParser and verify my findings ..

Comment: If you look at the python-uds repository, it has had no significant contributions since 2019, setup.py only says its "supported" in python 3.6 ..

Comment: There are *forks* of python-uds in github, maybe some of those might have that issue fixed ..